# Navbar TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am trying to implement a navbar to html which has the effect dynamically switch pages instead of changing links via `href`. The trick I'm using to accomplish this is by adding a `classList` of `is-active` to the `div` elements in the `section` tag.

Here is an example code of the generated HTML :
***navBar.js***

```
const navbarItem = [
    {
        navitem : "About",
        link: 1
    },
    {
        navitem : "Legal",
        link: 2
    },
    {
        navitem : "Contact",
        link: 3
    }
];

window.onload = function navLoad() {
    const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
    navbar.innerHTML = 
    `
        <div class="toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="tab is-active">
                <a onclick="renderNav()">Home</a>
            </li>
            ${navbarItem.map(loadNavitems).join(" ")}
        </ul>
    `
}

function loadNavitems(navItems) {
    return `
            <li class="tab">
                <a data-switcher data-id="${navItems.link}" onclick="renderNav(); navSwap();">${navItems.navitem}</a>
            </li>
        `
}

function renderNav(){
    const pages = document.getElementById('main');
    document.getElementById('alphabetButtons').style.display = "block";
    pages.innerHTML = 
    `
        <section class="pages">
             ${navbarItem.map(item => `
                <div class="page" data-page="${item.link}">
                    <h1>${item.navitem}</h1>
                </div>
             `).join('')}
        </section>
    `
};
```

And here is the code which takes care of the page switching:
***navSwitcher.js***

```
function navSwap() {
    const tab_switchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-switcher]');

    for (let input of tab_switchers) {
        const page_id = input.dataset.switcher;
        console.log(page_id);
        input.addEventListener('click', function () {
            
            if(document.querySelector('.nav-list .tab.is-active')){
                document.querySelector('.nav-list .tab.is-active').classList.remove('is-active');
                console.log('removed'); 
            }
            if(input.parentNode.classList.contains('tab')){
                input.parentNode.classList.add('is-active');
            }
            //SwitchNav(page_id);
        });
    }
}

function SwitchNav(page_id) {
    const currentPage = document.querySelector('.pages .page');
    const next_page = document.querySelector(`.pages .page[data-page="${page_id}"]`);
    console.log(next_page);
    if(document.querySelector('.pages .page.is-active')){
        document.querySelector('.pages .page.is-active').classList.remove('is-active');
    }
    next_page.classList.add('is-active');
    
}
```

***Update*** : The issue is that causes the error comes when attempting to place `[data-page="${page_id}"]` after `.page` inside the `querySelector`. When console logging, `[data-page="${page_id}"]` will return null. This is weird because `data-page` is named correctly in the `renderNav` function which holds the div of class page.

Hence my hypothesis now is that the issue comes from `[data-page="${page_id}"]` in the `SwitchNav(page_id)` function. ***My question is why is this occuring if everything is named correctly?***

***Fixes tried:***

- Attempted to change the for/of loop to a regular for loop inside the navSwap function.
- Inside the navSwap function, `const page_id = input.dataset.tab;` was changed to `const page_id = input.dataset.switcher;` which now returns 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging around, in the end it was actually `const page_id = tab_switcher.dataset.tab;` which was returning undefined, hence causing the error to happen. In reality it was returning `id` so I changed it to `tab_switcher.dataset.id;`.

Here is the final attempt at the code (i placed everything in one single file):
***navBar.js***:

```
const navbarItem = [
    {
        navitem : "About",
        link: 1
    },
    {
        navitem : "Legal",
        link: 2
    },
    {
        navitem : "Contact",
        link: 3
    }
];

window.onload = function navLoad() {
    
    const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
    navbar.innerHTML = 
    `
        <div class="toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="tab is-active">
                <a onclick="renderNav()">Home</a>
            </li>
            ${navbarItem.map(loadNavitems).join(" ")}
        </ul>
    `
}

function loadNavitems(navItems) {
    return `
            <li class="tab">
                <a data-switcher data-id="${navItems.link}" onclick="renderNav(); navSwap();">${navItems.navitem}</a>
            </li>
        `
}

function renderNav(){
    const pages = document.getElementById('main');
    document.getElementById('alphabetButtons').style.display = "block";
    pages.innerHTML = 
    `
        <section class="pages">
             ${navbarItem.map(item => `
                <div class="page" data-page="${item.link}">
                    <h1>${item.navitem}</h1>
                </div>
             `).join('')}
        </section>
    `
};

function navSwap() {
    const tab_switchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-switcher]');

    for (let i = 0; i < tab_switchers.length; i++) {
        const tab_switcher = tab_switchers[i];
        const page_id = tab_switcher.dataset.id;
        tab_switcher.addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.querySelector('.nav-list .tab.is-active').classList.remove('is-active');
            tab_switcher.parentNode.classList.add('is-active');
            SwitchNav(page_id);
        });
    }
}

function SwitchNav(page_id) {
    const currentPage = document.querySelector('.pages .page');
    const next_page = document.querySelector(`.pages .page[data-page="${page_id}"]`);
    console.log(next_page);
    if(document.querySelector('.pages .page.is-active')){
       currentPage.classList.remove('is-active');
    }
    if(document.querySelector('.pages .page')){
       next_page.classList.add('is-active');
    }
}
```

Although the code generates the intended results, I have to click twice on the  tag to fire it's onclick event. If anybody knows why this occurs it would be of much help to know in the comments.

Also let me know if this is a viable fix. Thanks again :)